# Data Streaming from Java EE Application Server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, streaming, ejb

I need to retrieve from an Application Server (JBoss) a large file (gigabytes) and to avoid loading it in memory, I want to stream it through EJB.

Is it possible to take data out of an Application Server as a stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html), stream the file.

**update**
Be careful with your header. You cannot set the ContentLength-Header via `setContentLength()`, because it only accept `int`.

You wil have to set it with: `setHeader("Content-Length", (long)length)`

Maybe this will be helpful: [Using ServletOutputStream to write very large files in a Java servlet without memory issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685271/using-servletoutputstream-to-write-very-large-files-in-a-java-servlet-without-me)

There is a limit, but it depends on the client-side. If the client will hold the file in the memory, it will not work.

Answer (score 4):

By *EJB* do you mean remote bean? These beans are typically based on RMI which in turn uses Java serialization. You cannot stream data using RMI.

However with servlets and HTTP this will be dead simple. Just open `FileInputStream` to your large file and copy it byte-by-byte to [servlet output](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29).

#### To remember:

- Use input file buffering
- At the very beginning set `Content-Length` header so that the client knows how much data is left